# Algorithm for filling table with all possible combinations of any number of questions

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have encountered some problem,
it would be great if you helped me

Well... I have to fill an html table with *all possible combinations*. I have any number of columns and each column has value of `"Yes"` or `"No"`, combinations *must be unique*. I couldn't come up with an effective algorithm

Thank you in advance

I have applied `"No"` to all values and after that I was adding one `"Yes"` to every row by sequence

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>No</td>  <td>No</td>  <td>No</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Yes</td> <td>No</td>  <td>No</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Yes</td> <td>Yes</td> <td>No</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Yes</td> <td>YES</td> <td>YES</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>No</td> <td>Yes</td> <td>No</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>No</td> <td>Yes</td> <td>Yes</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

and so on...
After that I applied `"Yes"` to all table and was replacing to `"No"` with same style after that I would merge them and find unique ones. But still i was missing some combinations like "yes no yes" things goes much more difficult for more columns

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sound like binary counting to me, where 0 is replaced by "No" and 1 by "Yes".

Comment: Why on earth is this tagged C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `answers` answers (`3` in you case), you can loop over `0..2^answers` range treating each bit set (`1`) as `Yes`, and reset (`0`) as `No`:

```
  0: 000 :  No  No  No
  1: 001 :  No  No Yes
  2: 010 :  No Yes  No
  ...
  7: 111 : Yes Yes Yes
```

This scheme can be easily implemented with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...  

int answers = 3;

var lines = Enumerable
  .Range(0, 1 << answers)
  .Select(i => Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(answers, '0'))
  .Select(s => string.Join(" ", s
     .Select(b => b == '1' ? "<td>Yes</td>" : "<td>No</td>")));

var body = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines
  .Select(line => $"<tr>{line}</tr>"));

var table = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
  "<table>", body, "</table>");

// Let' have a look
Console.Write(table);
```

**Outcome:**

```
<table>
<tr><td>No</td> <td>No</td> <td>No</td></tr>
<tr><td>No</td> <td>No</td> <td>Yes</td></tr>
<tr><td>No</td> <td>Yes</td> <td>No</td></tr>
<tr><td>No</td> <td>Yes</td> <td>Yes</td></tr>
<tr><td>Yes</td> <td>No</td> <td>No</td></tr>
<tr><td>Yes</td> <td>No</td> <td>Yes</td></tr>
<tr><td>Yes</td> <td>Yes</td> <td>No</td></tr>
<tr><td>Yes</td> <td>Yes</td> <td>Yes</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one simple way to do it:
Loop from `0` to the number of columns.
Convert the loop counter to binary using `Convert.ToString`.
replace `0` with `<td>No</td>` and `1` with `<td>Yes</td>`.
append it all to a string builder.
return the string.

```
string GenerateTable(int numberOfColumns)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.AppendLine("<Table>");
    for(var i = 0; i < Math.Pow(2, numberOfColumns); i++)
    {
        var str = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(numberOfColumns, '0');
        sb.Append("<tr>")
            .Append(str.Replace("0", "<td>No</td>").Replace("1", "<td>Yes</td>"))
            .AppendLine("</tr>");
    }
    return sb.AppendLine("</table>").ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, i appreciate it.
When i tested it unfortunately not all rows are unique, but still thanks for your answer